# if statement obj-c zero input

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, zero

here is code.

```
   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {

            int x,y;
            //BOOL divsibleYESOrNo;

            NSLog(@"enter two number for test it\n");
            scanf("%i %i",&x,&y);

            if ( x%y ==0 ) {

                NSLog(@"YES,it can be");
            }

            else if (x%y !=0) {
                NSLog(@"no there cant.");
            }
            else 
                NSLog(@"zero is not allow");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

this code can not detect if the user input two zero.
how can I modify this code that can detect the input values are zero?

Thanks

Comment: `if (0 == x || 0 == y) { // we got zero as input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything % 0 is undefined, so you'll need to add a check for y == 0 before your other if statements. It has to be the first if statement in order to make sure it gets evaluated; otherwise one of your other statements will catch it erroneously first.

```
if ( y == 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"zero is not allowed.");
}
else if ( x%y == 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"YES,it can be");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"no there cant.");
}
```

Comment: To clarify, in your question, only the first two conditionals will ever get evaluated at all. Either (x%y == 0) or (x%y != 0); one or the other must be true, so the last else never comes up. That's why the check for 0 has to come first.

Comment: can I put check zero after first true?

Comment: so the first "if" is just like the default in switch statement?

Comment: Not exactly. The last else functions more like a default, but what was happening is that you were getting a false match before it got to that point.

Comment: Hi,why I can not put 'zero' as second condition?, I want to the frist condition is true that can calculator the x%y.

Comment: The problem is that there's no telling what you'll get if you try to evaluate `x%y` when y == 0. It might evaluate as zero, or it might not, and both are mathematically wrong; the only way to prevent it triggering a false match is to filter that case out first.